# AWS - Cannot view Cloud 9 Environment created via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, development-environment, aws-cloud9

I am using the following CloudFormation code snippet to create a cloud9 environment. The Subnet specified is a public subnet in a VPC.

The cloudformation template completes successfully and creates an EC2 instance as well. However when I navigate to https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/home/product, I expect to see a list of Environments, all I see is the menu option below. How do I see a list of environments in the AWS Console and Open/Access the Environment?

[image]

```
  EnvironmentEC2:
    Type: AWS::Cloud9::EnvironmentEC2
    Properties:
      AutomaticStopTimeMinutes: 60
      Description: My Cloud9 Environment
      InstanceType: t2.small
      SubnetId:
        Ref: MySubnet
```

Answer (score 1):

Click the "three lines" icon in the top-left corner, then click **Your environments**.

Answer (score 0):

There was 1 core issue that had to be resolved.

I had to specify an additional parameter called **OwnerArn**. Since I was executing the cloudformation template using non-root but viewing the status using root. I did not realize this **before**, I was executing it under different sub-accounts.

I added this to the template in my original post.
**`OwnerArn: arn:aws:iam::xxxx00x:user`**

I believe if you have only 1 account you are dealing with you will not face this issue.

After I did this I was able to navigate to the environments via the menu option "Your environments". (I was not able to navigate before correctly)